# Device to divert printing to PDF

Tags: linux, pdf, printing, usb

I'm trying to build a device that is inserted between a client and a printer.
In the normal case this device should just allow the printing to occur as normal, but if a certain event happens it should instead divert the printing to a PDF file on disk.

In essence it should work as a print server that can decide where to send the data to be printed.

The problem is that I want to achieve this using an USB-A to USB-A cable between the client and the device, and the printer via USB to the device.

The device is at the moment a Raspberry Pie running Raspbian.
Printing *from* the Pie is tested using CUPS, so that works.

Now for the question(s):

How can I allow printing via USB cable from the client? Simply connecting the device and the client does not allow it to be recognised as a printer. CUPS does not seem to support this sharing option.

Can CUPS be configured to support sharing via USB?

Is there any other print software that supports this?

Is there another OS where this could be achieved easier?

Any input is appreciated!